# Rounded edge rectangles with Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there another way to add a rounded edge to square/rectangle shapes apart from drawing a circle and drawing a square over it? I am trying to make the YouTube logo using only Python turtle.  I didn't use absolute position functions like home(), as I need replicate this at different locations later on.

```
from turtle import *



def placement():
    penup()
    setheading(0)
    forward(5)
    setheading(90)
    forward(20)
    setheading(0)
    pendown()

def youtube():
    placement() #Custom Starting poisition
    hideturtle()
    pencolor("#d43b33") # Pen Color
    fillcolor("#d43b33") #Youtube Red Colour RGB Code
    begin_fill()
    forward(90)
    setheading(90) #Face Up
    forward(30)
    setheading(180) #Face Left
    forward(90)
    setheading(270) #Face Down
    forward(30)
    end_fill()
    setheading(0) #Second Half Youtube Logo
    forward(90)
    setheading(90)
    forward(30)
    pencolor("#fa453b") # Pen Color
    fillcolor("#fa453b") #Youtube Ligther Red Colour RGB Code
    begin_fill()
    forward(30)
    setheading(180) # Face Left
    forward(90)
    setheading(270) #Face Down
    forward(30)    
    setheading(0) #turn right
    forward(90)
    end_fill()
    penup()
    fillcolor("#ffffff") #Youtube White Play button RGB Code
    setheading(180)
    forward(55)
    setheading(90)
    begin_fill()
    forward(20)
    setheading(315)
    forward(30)
    setheading(225)
    forward(30)
    setheading(90)
    forward(20)
    end_fill()
```

[Draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o89r.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't believe that the YouTube logo is a [rounded rectangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RoundedRectangle.html), but rather a [hyperellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse).  But let's assume a rounded rectangle to keep things simple.  Second, I don't believe your colors, nor your arrow, conform to the [YouTube Brand](https://www.youtube.com/yt/about/brand-resources/#logos-icons-colors) so I'll adjust those things slightly:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def rounded_rectangle(turtle, short, long, radius):
    diameter = radius * 2

    heading = turtle.heading()
    turtle.setheading(270)

    isdown = turtle.isdown()
    if isdown:
        turtle.penup()

    turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() - long/2, turtle.ycor() - short/2 + radius)

    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.circle(radius, 90)
        turtle.forward(long - diameter)
        turtle.circle(radius, 90)
        turtle.forward(short - diameter)

    turtle.penup()  # restore turtle state, position and heading
    turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() + long/2, turtle.ycor() + short/2 - radius)
    if isdown:
        turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setheading(heading)

def youtube(turtle):
    turtle.color("#ff0000")  # YouTube red pen color RGB code

    turtle.begin_fill()
    rounded_rectangle(turtle, 60, 90, 10)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.penup()

    turtle.color("#ffffff")  # YouTube white play button RGB code
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.backward(8)
    turtle.setheading(90)

    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(12)
    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.forward(24)
    turtle.right(120)
    turtle.forward(12)
    turtle.end_fill()

def placement(turtle):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(5)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)

placement(yertle)  # Custom starting position

youtube(yertle)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I think I was look at older YouTube Logo, I have some question regarding using turtle as prefix as my rest of my code is not using turtle prefix(ie background) and I need implement these drawing function into same screen. Would I just make a function that calls on all need function and that should do the trick? For example `def draw():` nextline `youtube(Turtle(visible=False))`